# Object being destroyed on load of a scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a 2d platformer to add to my portfolio and I have ran into a bit of an issue that I hope someone can help me with

I have a button on a shop scene at the minute that adds 1 life when clicked in exchange for 1000 coins, the button stops working if the player does not have enough coins to purchase another life, that all works fine.

If I load straight into the shop scene I have no issue and everything works as it should, however if I load into the shop scene from a level after it has been completed the script from the button 'On click' is destroyed thus making the button inoperable.

I am using a game session script to control the shop, coin pickups etc, I have added a few bits to it and I think this is what is destroying the connection between the button and the script. During the levels the gamesession script is saying to destroy the coin objects on collision with the player, however when I "link" the gamesession script to the button on the shop scene it is destroyed on load, thus making the button inoperable. My current code is below:

```
private void Awake()
{
    {
        int numGameSessions = FindObjectsOfType<GameSession>().Length;
      
        if (numGameSessions > 1)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }
    
}

void Start()
{
    livesText.text = playerLives.ToString();
    scoreText.text = score.ToString();
}


private void TakeLife()
{
    playerLives--;
    var currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneIndex);
    livesText.text = playerLives.ToString();
}


public void AddToScore(int pointsToAdd)
{
    score += pointsToAdd;
    scoreText.text = score.ToString();
}

public void AddPlayerLives (int livesToAdd)
{
    if (score >= 1000)
    {
        playerLives++;
        livesText.text = playerLives.ToString();
        AddToScore(LifeCost);
    }

    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

public void ProcessPlayerDeath()
{
    if (playerLives >= 1)
    {
        TakeLife();
    }

    else
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game Lose");
    }
}

private void ResetGameSession()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

}

Thank you

Comment: Well, this can only mean that `numGameSessions > 1` condition is true every time that you load the scene and thus your object is destroyed because of `Destroy(gameObject);`. Change your condition, idk

Answer (score 0):

Change your Awake Script to this, because you currently only set `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);` when when the number of gamesession is smaller than 1. You can also check if there is already a Instance of that Object if check for `instane == null`

```
 void Awake()
 {
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the replies, I ended up sorting out my issue another way by creating a new script just for the shop and then using that to do the controlling of it.

Thank you again